# React native communication between view and business logic

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a view which has a button press -

```
import {businessLogic} from './BusinessLogic';

onButtonPressed = async() => {
   let response = await businessLogic();

   if (response) {
      //success
   } else {
      //error
   } 
}
```

The business logic will make the API call and it looks like this -

```
import { APICall} from './ApiClient'; 

export const businessLogic= async () => {

    try {
        let response = await APICall();
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const body = await response.json();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The ApiClient looks like this -

```
export const APICall= async () => {
    const reqOptions = {
        method: 'GET'
    };

    let tasksResponse = fetch('https://...', reqOptions);
    return tasksResponse;
}
```

My question is how do I differentiate the error response and exception in business logic and send to my view? Currently for error and exception I do return false but I need to do detailed error handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below approach to solve the problem:

Return the Object **{
        success: true,
        exception: false
      }** rather than the Boolean **true/false** value from business logic. based the value of Object you can make the decision in your screen.

The updated code with the above-mentioned approach.

**The business logic**

```js
import { APICall} from './ApiClient'; 

export const businessLogic= async () => {
    try {
        let response = await APICall();
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const body = await response.json();
            return {
              success: true,
              exception: false
            }
        } else {
            return {
              success: false,
              exception: false
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
      return {
        success: false,
        exception: true
      }
    }
}
```

**Using this Business Logic in View**

```js
import {businessLogic} from './BusinessLogic';

onButtonPressed = async() => {
   let response = await businessLogic();

   if (response.success) {
      // handle SUCCESS case
   }else if(response.exception){
      // handle EXCEPTION case here
   }else{
     // handle API ERROR case here
   }
}
```